# How to Scrape This Field?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

My code goes to the webpage and scrapes all of the authors, but I need the session name as well.

My current code will print just "SESSION" and not the value for the session

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 70)

driver.get('https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/results?filters=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')


productList=wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='record']")))
for product in productList:
        author=product.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='record__ellipsis']").text
        session=product.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='record__meta__title']").text
        print(session)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the session name use `xpath`:

```
//div[@class='record__meta ng-star-inserted'][1]/div[2]
```

To get session header, I'd use:

```
//div[@class='record__category ng-star-inserted']
```

And title:

```
//div[@class='record__title ng-star-inserted']/span
```

Comment: this seems to print all session values as "Moving Toward Equity" (which does not apply to all)

Comment: Yes, I thought you were asking for it. 1 min, I'll edit

Comment: i figured it out, needed a period before the // for the session. otherwise it prints repeating value.should be -->  .//div[@class='record__meta ng-star-inserted'][1]/div[2]    . thank you!

Comment: Yes, you need to put `.` for this case.

Comment: do you know why we need this **.**

Comment: Because you need direct children of your elements.

Answer (score 1):

For session try with this xpath `.//div[@class='record__meta ng-star-inserted' and contains(., 'Session')]`:

```
session=product.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='record__meta ng-star-inserted' and contains(., 'Session')]").text
```